# How to Create a List (via APIs) from a Large CSV in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, subscriber

I wrote some code to interact with Marketing Cloud's SOAP API to create a List and populate Subscribers by importing a CSV file.  The code works fine for CSVs up to a couple of thousand records.  I create a List record, then a SubscriberList record.  Then I pass in an array of records, loop through the array of records, and then create Subscriber records.

However, when I tried running my code with the last list (28k rows), it failed.  Is there a recommended way to programmatically create a List and Subscriber records by importing a large CSV?

Comment: Are you passing the CSV via the API payload or importing it via the FTP?

Comment: I was passing it via the API payload.  And this works for CSVs with only a couple of thousand records.  But it's failing for the 28k CSVs that we have.

Comment: yes, there is a limit per API call of around 2500 (or abouts, don't remember exact number) records. You would need to separate this call into multiple calls, or (the more efficient way) use the API to create the list, another to push the CSV to the SFMC FTP and then use the API to initiate the import into your new list.

Comment: Ah.  That makes sense.  Well ok.  I have the code working to create a List.  That shouldn't be a problem.  

However, I haven't seen anything in their documentation about FTP'ing the CSV to their system and then being able to reference it after the fact.

Comment: Moving the CSV to the FTP would be something you would need on your 3rd party system. It should be identical to any normal FTP, just use username/pass combo as well as FTP address (similar to Filezilla needs). Then finally you create the import definition (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_an_import_definition.htm)

Comment: Ah.  OK.  So I just need to find what the FTP info is for where to upload the CSV, correct?  And once that's done, I create the Import Definition which will import the contents of the FTP'd CSV into the List record, correct?

Comment: Correct. basically: 1.) Create List 2.) Gather FTP info and make API call to drop CSV to SFMC FTP 3.) Create and run Import Definition to upload from FTP